# Nativescript App crashes after deploying

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, nativescript

I'm new to this Nativescript and Android. Following the [tutorial here](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1)
When I start the App with `tns run android` or `tns run android --emulator` it runs well but when I run `tns livesync android` the App crashes with the below error.

```
tns livesync android
Project successfully prepared (android)
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all files.
Applying changes...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.sampleGroceries on device emulator-5554.
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:865)
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:730)
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:716)
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:697)
W/System.err( 2387):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:687)
```

Anyone knows how I could fix this?
I'm running this on windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: try  removing this folders : `hooks`,`node_modules`,`platforms` and run `tns livesync android` agin

Comment: No `hooks` folder in the project directory. Removing `node_modules` obviously the app will not run again, that's where Nativescript libraries reside, same as removing `platforms` they wouldn't be any application to run because that's where both `android` and `iOS` platforms are. There might be other ways, I don't think your idea will work. Haven't tried though.

Comment: when you run tns livesync android they all be installed again. removing and re install them fixed lots of problems of that kind for me